# List of strings to attribute list

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have a report which was built on MDX-query:

```
SELECT {[Measures].[IssueOpened] } ON COLUMNS,
       {(  STRTOSET("[Assigned To].[Id].[Some],[Assigned To].[Id].[Another]") * 
         [Priorities].[Id].[Id].ALLMEMBERS ) } ON ROWS
FROM (SELECT (STRTOSET(@createdOn) ) ON COLUMNS
     FROM [Reports])
```

I want to change static string *"[Assigned To].[Id].[Some]:[Assigned To].[Id].[Another]"* to parameter:

```
SELECT {[Measures].[IssueOpened] } ON COLUMNS,
       {(  STRTOSET(@assignedTo) * 
         [Priorities].[Id].[Id].ALLMEMBERS ) } ON ROWS
FROM (SELECT (STRTOSET(@createdOn) ) ON COLUMNS
     FROM [Reports])
```

I have created parameter, but **Available values** for this paramater is relation dataset (not MDX dimension). **Allow multiple values** set to *Yes*.

How can I convert value of parameter to list of atributes: *"[Assigned To].[Id].[Some],[Assigned To].[Id].[Another]"*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to create CLR stored procedure for analysis services which will do it for you, so it would build the SET for you. You can find some examples on google. (i.e. http://andrewdenhertog.com/analysis-services/clr-stored-procedures-in-sql-server-analysis-services-ssas/)

Comment: Thanks. Looks like what I want. I'll try to use it.

Answer (score 0):

If these come from a relational data source I just encode them in the format that MDX is expecting for the parameter value property for example:

Parameter Label: Some
Parameter Value: [Assigned To].[Id].[Some]

Some time this turns out to be easy to create in TSQL Other times you need to do a little hacking with expressions if you need to support dynamic hierarchies. role playing dimensions would be an example. The basic concept is similar though.